# Connect with SQL Server 2008 Express using Winforms (C#)

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, sql-server-2008-express

I am creating the database from coding in Winforms (C#) and also run the script for creating the tables.

In short I create the database using the Winforms (C#) in SQL Server Express.

But when I run my application I get this error :

> Cannot open database '' requested by the login. the login failed. login failed for user 'KETAN\admin'.

My connection string:

```
Server=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=True;database=mydatabasename;User Id=myusername;Password=mypassword;
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: As you can see on error message, your connection string _actually_ try to with your windows credentials (`KETAN\admin`), not sql server authentication because of `Integrated Security` part. Marc _already_ explained this very well.

Comment: I am connecting with sql express not to server and my sql express userid is KETAN-ASP\SQLEXPRESS and i also remove integrated security part and provide userid and password but still getting this error.

Answer (score 3):

If you have **both**

```
Integrated Security=True;
```

and

```
User Id=myusername;Password=mypassword;
```

in your connection string, then the `Integrated Security` wins and the specific user and password are **ignored**, and the connection is attempted with your current Windows credentials (`KETAN\admin`) and that doesn't seem to work

So just change your connection string to:

```
Server=.\SQLEXPRESS;database=mydatabasename;User Id=myusername;Password=mypassword;
```

Now, your specific user and its password will be used to connect to SQL Server, and if those are correct, you should be able to connect just fine

Comment: i removed that u suggest me but even though it will give me below error : can not open database 'mydatabasename' requested by login. The login failed for user 'sa'